# Can't convert nvarchar to datetime

Tags: datetime, nvarchar

I have cells like 'Dec  6 2016  6:26AM' (copied from DB) in NVARCHAR. I want to convert that to the Datetime format . But every time when I try do that there are the error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime'.
I do not understand what is the problem, because my cell is absolutely similar to Datetime 100 format.

For deciding the problem I have alreade tried:
convert and cast (do not work), Try_convert and Try_ cast do not work too (get me nulls only), creating a new table with needed column format and inserting into that my data and etc.

The exprected result is opportunity to use DATEDIFF function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```sql
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'Dec 6 2016 6:26AM',100);
```

gives the result:

```sql
    2016-12-06 06:26:00.000
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, CAST and TRY_Convert/Cast too